# Java - a generic numbers method

Tags: java

Although I use here Hamcrest library, it is probably not an Hamcrest issue but pure Java...

I have the following method:

```
public static void isGreaterThan(int valueToValidate, int minExpectedVal) {
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(valueToValidate, greaterThan(minExpectedVal));
}
```

I'd like to generalize it to something like:

```
public static <T> void isGreaterThan(T valueToValidate, T minExpectedVal) {
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(valueToValidate, greaterThan(minExpectedVal));
}
```

or

```
public static void isGreaterThan(Number valueToValidate, Number minExpectedVal) {
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(valueToValidate, greaterThan(minExpectedVal));
}
```

Hamcrest greaterThan signature is:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> Matcher<T> greaterThan(T value)
```

and assertThat signature:

```
<T> void assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)
```

However, on both cases, I get an error on minExpectedVal saying that it cannot be applied as T.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: As per hamcrest signature your Typed parameter should inherit comparable interface. As per docs Number class is not inheriting from Comparable interface

Comment: @dushkin You have a misconception about what `java.lang.Number` represents. It is not a generic number type, as the name would suggest. The name is misleading, as it only represents an *object that can be converted to any of the primitive numeric types*. That conversion is not lossless and that is the reason why it does not implement `Comparable`. And that is why it really cannot be used to represent a number as one would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a bound to your generic version.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void isGreaterThan(T valueToValidate, T minExpectedVal) {
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(valueToValidate, greaterThan(minExpectedVal));
}
```

Note that `Number`s are *not* comparable; for them you could do

```
public static void isGreaterThan(Number valueToValidate, Number minExpectedVal) {
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(valueToValidate.doubleValue(), greaterThan(minExpectedVal.doubleValue()));
}
```

EDIT: Torben is correct that `doubleValue()` is not necessarily lossless. However, the only standard `Number` subtypes for which it isn't are `Long`, `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`, so you could check for them explicitly. But the generic version is better either way.

Comment: Please see my comment in the original question. `Number` is not meant to be used like this. The conversion to double will lose information so the comparison it is not accurate and should not be relied upon.

Comment: @Torben Good point, see the edit.